# How to define a name for a foreign key in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

For example I have several tables represented by this pseudo code:

```
let user = sequelize.define('User', /* attributes */);
let task = sequelize.define('Task', /* attributes */);

task.belongsTo(user, { foreignKey: "userId" });

sequelize.sync();
```

The resulting `task` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `userId` (`userId`),
    CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

It generates foreign key name `task_ibfk_1`

**So the questions are:**

1. how to change a foreign key name for column manually by sequelize?
2. is it possible to create index and foreign keys in the same way for migrations?
3. is it possible to create foreign keys by sequelize at all?

In some cases I'm using `query-generator` but it doesn't provide too much.

Notes:

As I see for now (12/21/2016) this feature is in progress for a long time: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5212

Related issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/966

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using migrations:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE task ADD CONSTRAINT task_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES user(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION;");
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE task DROP FOREIGN KEY task_ibfk_1;");
  }
};
```

Comment: it can be done like this as you suggested but why then do we need an interface for migrations at all if we can write SQL by our own?! :)